# Maximizing the sum of 2-norms of scaled vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, optimization

Given $\alpha$ = {$\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, $\alpha_3$, ... , $\alpha_n$}, where 1> $\alpha_i$> 0, and $\alpha_i \ne \alpha_j$ $\forall i , j \in {1,n}$ and $\alpha_1<\alpha_2<\alpha_3<...\alpha_n$.

We need to find scales $\kappa=\{\kappa_1, \kappa_2, \kappa_3, ..., \kappa_n\}$ $\in$ $\sigma (\alpha)$,

where, $\sigma(.)$ is the permuation of the set $\alpha$ such that for a given set of vectors V = {$V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$, ..., $V_n$}, we can maximize $\sum_i\sum_j\lVert \kappa_iV_i-\kappa_jV_j\rVert_2$.

Answer (score 0):

First, we must understand what the problem asks us to do. We are given a set of vectors, and we want to find a set of scales for each vector such that the sum of the Euclidean distances between all pairs of scaled vectors is maximized.

One way to approach this problem is to use the fact that the given set of scales $\alpha$ are sorted in increasing order. We can start by setting $\kappa_1 = 1$ (without loss of generality) and then consider the possible scaling factors for the remaining vectors.

For each vector $V_i$, we can scale it by any factor in the set $\{\alpha_j/\alpha_2\}$, where $j$ ranges from 2 to $i$ (since $\alpha_1$ is already used for $V_1$). This is because scaling by a factor greater than $\alpha_i/\alpha_1$ would lead to a smaller distance between $V_i$ and any other vector.

Once we have considered all possible scaling factors for each vector, we can compute the pairwise distances between all scaled vectors and find the maximum sum. This can be done by brute force, but there are more efficient algorithms for this task.

The Hungarian algorithm is a combinatorial optimization algorithm used to solve the assignment problem in weighted bipartite graphs. In other words, given a set of $n$ workers and $n$ jobs, with each worker having a cost for performing each job, the algorithm finds the optimal assignment of workers to jobs such that the total cost is minimized.

The algorithm works by iteratively finding a set of augmenting paths in the graph. An augmenting path starts at an unmatched worker and goes through a series of edges that connect unmatched workers to unmatched jobs and ends at an unmatched job. Once an augmenting path is found, the unmatched edges along the path are flipped, corresponding to changing the workers' assignment to jobs. This process is repeated until no more augmenting paths can be found, at which point the optimal assignment has been found.

The Hungarian algorithm has a time complexity of $O(n^3)$, where $n$ is the number of workers (or jobs). This makes it very efficient for solving small to medium-sized assignment problems, but it can become impractical for very large problems.